# What is the proper way to structure Swift UIViews and UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift

Does the UIViewController simply manage what UIViews are displayed? Or is it also used to control the contents within them?

For example, right now I currently have code in my UIViewController that switches from one view to the next based on a button click which looks like this:

```
class TTViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        super.view.addBackground()
    }

    //other code 

    @IBAction func OpenUserSelectView(sender: AnyObject) {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "PlayerSelectView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        super.view.addSubview(view)
    } 
}
```

But I also have UIViews that do things like create buttons, have actions for those buttons, as well as other things which looks like this:

```
class PlayerSelectView :UIScrollView {
    let viewWidth = CGFloat(300)
    let viewHeight = CGFloat(500)
    var addPlayerButton :TTBlueButton?
    var cancel :TTBlueButton?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        self.frame = CGRectMake((screenSize.width/2) - (viewWidth/2), (screenSize.height/2) - (viewHeight/2), viewWidth, viewHeight)

        styleView()
        addAddPlayerButton()

        self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(viewWidth, viewHeight-100)
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    func styleView() {
        super.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        super.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        super.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        super.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
        super.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 5.0)
    }

    func addAddPlayerButton(){
        addPlayerButton = TTBlueButton(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, viewWidth-20, 40))
        addPlayerButton!.setTitle("Add New Player", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        addPlayerButton!.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        addPlayerButton!.userInteractionEnabled = true
        addPlayerButton!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PlayerSelectView.addPlayer(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        self.addSubview(addPlayerButton!)
    }

    func addCancelButton(){
        addPlayerButton = TTBlueButton(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, viewWidth-20, 40))
        addPlayerButton!.setTitle("Cancel", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        addPlayerButton!.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        addPlayerButton!.userInteractionEnabled = true
        addPlayerButton!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PlayerSelectView.addPlayer(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        self.addSubview(addPlayerButton!)
    }

    @IBAction func addPlayer(sender: AnyObject) {

        if addPlayerButton?.currentTitle != "Create Player" {
            let addPlayerTextField = TextField(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: viewWidth - 20, height: 40))
            let border = CALayer()
            let width = CGFloat(2.0)
            addPlayerButton!.setTitle("Create Player", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:  addPlayerTextField.frame.size.width, height: addPlayerTextField.frame.size.height)
            border.borderWidth = width
            border.cornerRadius = 5
            addPlayerTextField.layer.addSublayer(border)
            addPlayerTextField.layer.masksToBounds = true

            self.addSubview(addPlayerTextField)
            addPlayerButton?.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 60)
        } else {

        }

    }
}
```

Something about the way I've done this feels wrong so I was wondering if my suspicions were correct or if this is an acceptable way of doing this.

Comment: MVC. Model View Controller. A View merely displays. A Controller controls - including controlling what views appear.

Answer (score 1):

You can do whatever you like, but in my opinion, code configuration of what views appear goes into a controller (e.g. a view controller - note the name).

You don't have to do everything in *one* view controller - you can nest view controllers - but what you are showing is controller code and should (in my opinion) be in a view controller.

Answer (score 1):

> As the name suggests, a View Controller manages a set of Views and is
>   an instance of the Class UIViewController. Their job is to manage
>   things like view resizing, layouts, reacting to interaction with
>   views, handling events such as motion or touch, and coordinating with
>   data models or even other view controllers.

You need to study view naigation using navigation controller.beacuse on the above code you are adding a view into your's uiviewcontroller's view,and also the code have some memory leak too.

make one or more child view controllers and do what ever you want on that view controller.after that when you click a button from parent viewcontroller push your child view controller using uinavigationcontroller

Comment: So is there a purpose for having a customized UIView? What kind of code would be in there? I have another UI view that utilizes the drawRect function to put squares on the view, so would that be an appropriate use? Another example of something that I feel like should remain in the UIView would be whatever is in the styleView function and the init (minus the addAddPlayerButton function).